# Inno Setup: How to create batch file and run it after install is done

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

i want to **create** a batchfile and run it, after the installation is done. I found a tutorial here: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/477984/createplusandpluswriteplusbatchplusfileplusinplusi

So I started to type this bunch of code here into my [Code] section:

```
function CreateInstallDatabaseBatch(): boolean;
var
  fileName: string;
  line: string;
begin
  Result:= True;
  fileName:= ExpandConstant('{sd}\{#MyAppName}\Temp\installdatabase.bat');
  line:= 'sqlcmd -S ' + srvName + ' -i {sd}\{#MyAppName}\Temp\installdatabase.sql';
  Result:= SaveStringToFile(fileName, line, true);
  exit;
end;

procedure installdb(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep=ssDone then
  begin
    CreateInstallDatabaseBatch();
  end;
end;
```

It compiles without any error and install my package without any errors, but it doesnt create the batch file with that one line. Do I have to add something? I just added the code parts that are showed in the tutorial and edited them a bit (i.e. I just need one line, not lines).

If you need any further information, please tell me. Ill reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `CurStepChanged` from the [original code](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/477984/createplusandpluswriteplusbatchplusfileplusinplusi#answer1) is an [Inno Setup event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents). You cannot rename it.
2. Make sure the `{sd}\{#MyAppName}\Temp` exists. Why don't you use an installer temporary folder (`{tmp}`) instead?
3. You have to use the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) to expand the `{sd}` constant in the `{sd}\{#MyAppName}\Temp\installdatabase.sql` (just as with the path to the batch file). You should better wrap the path to double-quotes too.
4. For a single command, you do not need to create a batch file. Just run the command directly using the [`ShellExec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Params: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    Params :=
      '-S ' + srvName + ' ' +
      '-i "' + ExpandConstant('{sd}\{#MyAppName}\Temp\installdatabase.sql') + '"';
    ShellExec('', 'sqlcmd', Params, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried to do it like you said in step 4, because I just need to execute one command. To check if my string "Params" is correct, I used a MsgBox. Following problem: The srvName variable is declared and attached to a value in another procedure (InitializeWizard). Its the server name, which the user has to put in an input field. 

How I did this: `srvName:= ServerDataPage.Values[1]`

Comment: * But the name doesnt appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot do `srvName:= ServerDataPage.Values[1]` in `InitializeWizard`. At that point the box has no value yet! Use the `ServerDataPage.Values[1]` directly in the `CurStepChanged`, instead of the `srvName` variable. Like `'-S ' + ServerDataPage.Values[1] + ' ' +`.